# wrong architecture error mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

i use flask.I installed MySQL using `easy_install mysql-python` and then tried to run my app.py but got this lines of error.What is those mean?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/ozcan/Documents/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: Perhaps some issue related to PPC vs Intel on Macs. Try `lipo -info /Users/ozcan/Documents/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so` and `file /Users/ozcan/Documents/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so`

Comment: now it works,i guess your solution was correct,thank you very much

Comment: You can post how you fixed it as an answer, so other people with the same problem now what to do.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use Flask-MySQL instead.
Here's documentation https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: this is not my question's answer.Anyway thanks for the advise.